# Having Issue on Over Writing Bootstrap 3 Breadcrumbs Separator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change the Bootstrap 3 Breadcrumbs Separator from `/` to `glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right` [image] by using the following rule

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
    content: "\e092" !important;
}
```

but the result is empty square instead of arrow! Please take a look at the demo and let me know why this is not working?

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/p2rr8Txaa2)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the font-family to your css code there so:

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e092" !important;
}
```

Best.

Comment: In Bootstrap, it looks like the icon font is mapped to the `glyphicon` class name, which wasn't used here, so you do have to bring your own font in.